# Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException when adding AndroidActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

I followed a tutorial to add android `ActionBar` to my Api 7 Android Project. My code seems to be good, but I get this error:

```
[2013-12-20 10:18:57 - Dex Loader] Unable to executedex:java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2013-12-20 10:18:57 - android-actionbar-for-2.x.x] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
```

My properties and manifest files:

Project project.properties:

```
1- android.library.reference.1=../../Documents/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat
2- target=android-7
3- sdk.buildtools=18.1.1
```

SupportV7AppCompat project.properties

```
1- target=android-7
2- sdk.buildtools=18.1.1
3- android.library=true
```

Project Manifest:

```
1- <uses-sdk
2- android:minSdkVersion="7"
3- android:targetSdkVersion="7" />
```

SupportV7AppCompat Manifest:

```
1- <uses-sdk 
2-  android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

Comment: Added this "sdk.buildtools=18.1.1" project.propertis.

Comment: I already have those lines in my project but that doesn't change, i have still the same error

Answer (score 0):

See this link i have provided solution for this

also note that if you had added

```
 <uses-sdk
 android:minSdkVersion="7"
 android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Target sdk should b latest or ad `android:maxSdkVersion="19"` instead of  `android:targetSdkVersion="19"`

[Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778767/unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverflowexception-check-the-eclipse-log-f/21137273#21137273)